# For loop displaying last value only in HTML input element

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

i have an issue with my input only is display me last value but the value if exist because in console and alert function is showed.
the code work perfectly some years ago and now stopped working.

When i said "stopped working" mean that data rows no is display one after another on inputs field as it did before, only i can  see  rows data one after another if  concatenate value to alert dialog or console, and  imputs keeps emptys until the loop is finished.
Previously, the row values was display one after another on the inputs ield and stoped with the alert function but i saw the imputs populate in all the iterationes and now  only see the last value.

I have 3 files.

- funcionajax.js.
- Principal.html.
- PHPinvocado.php.
  this just return 3 records on json format, something like the following.

```
[{"nombre":"Josue","apellido":"Becerra","telefono":"3741021534"},{"nombre":"Ernesto","apellido":"Rodriguez","telefono":"3741034234"},{"nombre":"Alberto","apellido":"Jimenez","telefono":"3861023421"}]
```

- funcionajax.js code

```
function MostrarDatos(){
        
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var caja1 = document.getElementById("txtnombre");
        var caja2 = document.getElementById("txtap");
        var caja3 = document.getElementById("txttel");
    
    hr.open("GET", "PHPinvocado.php", true);
    hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
            
            
                    for(var obj in data){
                        
                alert("row found."+ data[obj].nombre+" "+data[obj].apellido+" "+data[obj].telefono);
                console.log(data[obj].nombre+" "+data[obj].apellido+" "+data[obj].telefono);
                
                caja1.value=""+data[obj].nombre;
                caja2.value=""+data[obj].apellido;
                caja3.value=""+data[obj].telefono;
            }
            
        }
    }
    hr.send(null);
    
}
```

- Principal.html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ejemplo2</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="funcionajax.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<label style="margin-left: 2%"><strong>Esta es la pagina del ejemplo 2:</strong></label><br><br><br>
<label style="margin-left: 2%"><strong>Nombre:</strong></label>
   <input id="txtnombre" name="nombre" type="text" />
   
<label style="margin-left: 2.5%">Apellido:</label>
   <input id="txtap" name="AP" type="text" />
   
<label style="margin-left: 3%">Telefono:</label>
   <input id="txttel" name="AM" type="text" />
   
<input type="button" onClick="MostrarDatos()" value="Buscar">
</body>
</html>
```

- PHPinvocado.php

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "dbejemplo");

    if (!$link) {
        die("No se puede conectar a la base de datos: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

$sql = "SELECT *FROM tablaalunmos";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        
$arreglo=array(
        "nombre"=>$row['nombre'],
        "apellido"=>$row['apellido'],
        "telefono"=>$row['telefono'],
                                                                
            );
            
    $total[]=$arreglo; //agrega una nueva fila 'registro' en la posision que le sigue...

    }

} else {
    $arreglo=array("empty"=>"No hay resulado");
    $total[]=$arreglo; 
}

mysqli_close($link);
echo json_encode($total);
?>
```

[image: first rows only in console and funtion alert]

[image: last row in inputs too]

Comment: yeah but before is the function alert, which stop ultil press button ok . it should look like ( minute 1.27-1:37 ) https://youtu.be/f_WPLye-ec4?t=87

Comment: I understand the iteration, but before I could see how each row was displayed before each alert dialog and now they only appear in the alert function and in the console and only the last is display like on video.

Comment: I thank you but you didn't understand my problem,
The problem is that in the first iteration you should place the value and obviously it will overwrite it.
but before I click ok( dialog alert) I should see value.

Comment: OK, since there's not even a `forEach` loop I guess I'm looking in the wrong place then

Comment: Is this a JS problem, a PHP problem, or an HTML problem? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "stopped working"? Please share all details **in text form** and add them to your question by editing it, not to the comment section

Comment: @kcire_eae Did the answers help you at all? Feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your script does exactly what it is supposed to do: it parses an array of addresses from the JSON server response, shows them, one after another in an alert message and then puts the data values into your input fields. As you are *overwriting* the values into these three input fields, only the last entries will remain visible there after your loop has finished.

In the script below I have replaced your PHP backend with a simple sample  API and changed the property names accordingly:

```js
function MostrarDatos(){
    
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var caja1 = document.getElementById("txtnombre");
    var caja2 = document.getElementById("txtap");
    var caja3 = document.getElementById("txttel");

hr.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
        
                // console.log(data);
                for(var obj in data){
                    
            alert("row found."+ data[obj].username+" "+data[obj].name+" "+data[obj].phone);
            // console.log(data[obj].nombre+" "+data[obj].apellido+" "+data[obj].telefono);
            
            caja1.value=""+data[obj].username;
            caja2.value=""+data[obj].name;
            caja3.value=""+data[obj].phone;
        }
        
    }
}
hr.send(null);

}
```

```html
<label style="margin-left: 2%"><strong>Esta es la pagina del ejemplo 2:</strong></label><br><br><br>
<label style="margin-left: 2%"><strong>Nombre:</strong></label>
   <input id="txtnombre" name="nombre" type="text" />
   
<label style="margin-left: 2.5%">Apellido:</label>
   <input id="txtap" name="AP" type="text" />
   
<label style="margin-left: 3%">Telefono:</label>
   <input id="txttel" name="AM" type="text" />
   
<input type="button" onClick="MostrarDatos()" value="Buscar">
</body>
</html>
```

As mentioned before, using `alert()` as a debugging tool is not the wisest choice - but it basically works. Only: *the page does not get refreshed after showing each alert message*. I believe this is a change in the way modern browsers behave now. The YouTube video you are referring to appears to be seven years old and was recorded using a browser of that time with a different rendering approach.

Also: You could simplify your script considerably by replacing the old `XMLHttpRequest()`-based AJAX call with a simpler promise based `fetch().then()` construct.

Comment: The result is same "Clementina DuBuque" last value, maybe the one reason is just the time the video and the modern browsers.
i  not use the alert to debugging, the video is mine and just wanted know why don´t work like before.(same files,database,server).
now just in console is work, the inputs keeps empty ultil last row. and that is weird.
but thank very much,I aprreciate it

Answer (score 0):

As @CarstenMassmann implied in their answer: You cannot expect the browser to redraw in between function calls nor behind a modal dialogue (which blocks the UI). Just to get it back working, you could add a small delay right after assigning the values to the text fields by using a non blocking function. While this is not guaranteed to work, it probably will.

```
var data = [{"nombre":"Josue","apellido":"Becerra","telefono":"3741021534"},{"nombre":"Ernesto","apellido":"Rodriguez","telefono":"3741034234"},{"nombre":"Alberto","apellido":"Jimenez","telefono":"3861023421"}];
async function MostrarDatos() {
    var caja1 = document.getElementById("txtnombre");
    var caja2 = document.getElementById("txtap");
    var caja3 = document.getElementById("txttel");
    for(var obj in data){
        alert("row found."+ data[obj].nombre+" "+data[obj].apellido+" "+data[obj].telefono);
        console.log(data[obj].nombre+" "+data[obj].apellido+" "+data[obj].telefono);
        
        caja1.value=""+data[obj].nombre;
        caja2.value=""+data[obj].apellido;
        caja3.value=""+data[obj].telefono;
        await Sleep(100);
    }
}
function Sleep(milliseconds) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds));
}
```

Tested to be working in Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Edge on Mac. [Here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0zt1r6L/)